# Auto-close a JOptionPane in a for loop

Tags: java

I am a bit lost, I have asked my professor the same question and I don't really understand how to implement the answer.  My code (below) basically creates 7 ImageIcon's, then I implement a for loop where it randomly calls the pictures.  This works fine, my question is how do I leave each ImageIcon up for 250ms, then have it close without input from the user and then move on to the next image until the for loop is completed?

```
package test;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TEST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create a timer

        //try to assign variables to pictures in an array
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/A_Guitar");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A Note", "A Note with Guitar", 
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon);        

        ImageIcon icon1 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/B_Guitar");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "B Note", "B Note with Guitar", 
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon1);


        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/C_Guitar");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "C Note", "C  Note with Guitar", 
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon2);

        ImageIcon icon3 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/D_Guitar");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "D Note", "D Note with Guitar", 
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon3);

        ImageIcon icon4 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/E_Guitar");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "E Note", "E Note with Guitar", 
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon4);

        ImageIcon icon5 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/F_Guitar");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "F Note", "F Note with Guitar", 
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon5);        

        ImageIcon icon6 = new ImageIcon("/home/james/programmingpics/G_Guitar");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "F Note", "F Note with Guitar", 
        JOptionPane.OK_OPTION, icon6);

        ImageIcon[] iconarray = {icon, icon1, icon2, icon3, icon4, icon5, icon6};

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int random = 1 * (int) ((Math.random() * 100) % 7);
            System.out.println(iconarray[random]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JDialog is more useful than JOptionPane in such cases.

Comment: I am ok with anything that will get this to work, I am just not familiar with JDialog quite yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Robot" Class in Java.awt.robot and a timer to simule a "User's imput" and close the JOptionPane after some time.